# Algorithm for determining changes between 2 lists as quicky as possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Projects.

These projects are downloaded from Site A into my site via an API.

I download all Projects from Site A.

There are matching JSON objects on my side. What is important is I need to do this.

List A (My site) needs to be Synced with List B (Their site).

I have to manually sync due to their api limits.

So there are projects and attributes:

Given list A and List B. What would be a fast algorithm so that:

```
If A is missing object from B, add it.
If B no longer contains an element found in A, remove it from A.
If an attribute in B is != an attribute in an object from A, update the object in A.
```

I feel like the only way to do a lot of this would be O (N^2). Is there a way to get better than O(N^2) on some of this?

Thanks

Comment: You can sort two lists in O(n log n) time. Can you think of an algorithm to compare two sorted lists that would operate in linear time?

Comment: Using HashSet and/or some LINQ Joins/Unions/Excepts is rather trivial. The former likely leads to better bounds, but the latter can be .. well, more LINQ'y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some HashSet implementation to check "Contains" condition also should give average complexity of less than n^2

Comment: Note: this approach works great if the elements are **unique** (i.e. no duplicate elements).

Comment: Correct, but looks like Milo already has mechanisms to identify uniqueness of some sort, if he finds and removes duplicates between lists

Answer (score 0):

> A is missing object from B, add it.

```
listA.AddRange(listB.Except(listA)); //note O(N+M) not O(N*M)
```

> If B no longer contains an element found in A, remove it from A.

```
listA.RemoveAll(listA.Except(listB)); //note O(N+M) not O(N*M)
```

> If an attribute in B is != an attribute in an object from A, update the object in A.

```
 //note O(N+M) not O(N*M)
var pairs = listA.Join(listB, 
    item => item.Key, 
    item => item.Key, 
    (a, b) => new { a, b });

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    //compare the properties of the items and mutate `pair.a` as appropriate
}
```

Note that the asymptotic complexity of all of these algorithms is the sum of the size of both sets *not* the product of the size of both sets.  `Except` and `Join` will each create a set-based data structure containing all of the items in one of the input sequences and then iterate over the other, using O(1) set based operations.